# Troubleshooting Inconsistent File Download Issues from SharePoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having issues with this class that I'm using to download files from SharePoint. The reason I'm reaching out here is that sometimes this method works correctly, and other times it doesn't and displays the error I'm attaching below.

```java
package xyz.derivadas.provider.sharepoint;




/**
 * Realiza las inteeracciones con Sharepoint.
 */
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SharePointClient {

    private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
    private static final String BEARER = "Bearer ";
    private static final String ACCEPT = "Accept";
    private static final String APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM = "application/octet-stream";
    private static final String DRIVE_ROOT_SEARCH_TOKEN = "/drive/root/search(q='";
    private static final String DRIVE_ROOT_SEARCH_TOKEN_CLOSE = "')";
    private static final String CHARSET_JSON_SHAREPOINT_RESPONSE = "UTF-8";
    private static final String SITES_TOKEN_VALUE = "value";
    private static final String EXPECTED_TOKEN_ID = "id";
    private final SharePointProperties sharePointProperties;

    /**
     * Autentica en Microsoft Azure.
     *
     * @return {@link IAuthenticationResult}
     * @throws Exception Si algo falla
     */
    private IAuthenticationResult authenticate() throws Exception {
        ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication
            .builder(sharePointProperties.getClientId(), ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(sharePointProperties.getClientSecret()))
            .authority(sharePointProperties.getAuthority() + sharePointProperties.getTenantId())
            .build();

        ClientCredentialParameters parameters = ClientCredentialParameters
            .builder(Collections.singleton(this.sharePointProperties.getGraphDefaultSchema()))
            .build();

        return app.acquireToken(parameters).join();
    }

    /**
     * Descarga un fichero (previa autenticacion)
     *
     * @param fileUrl       URL en SharePoint
     * @param localFilePath Ruta donde descargarlo.
     * @throws Exception Si algo falla
     */
    @Async
    public Optional<Integer> downloadFile(String fileUrl, String localFilePath) throws Exception {
        checkFileExists(localFilePath);

        IAuthenticationResult result = authenticate();
        String accessToken = result.accessToken();

        final String graphDownloadUrl = convertToGraphDownloadUrl(fileUrl);

        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(graphDownloadUrl);
            httpGet.addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, BEARER + accessToken);
            httpGet.addHeader(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet)) {
                log.trace("downloadFile response = {}", response);
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    if (entity != null) {
                        try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(localFilePath)) {
                            entity.writeTo(outputStream);
                        }
                    }
                    return Optional.of(statusCode);
                } else {
                    final String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), CHARSET_JSON_SHAREPOINT_RESPONSE);
                    log.error("Error en la descarga del fichero. El codigo de estado no es 200.");
                    log.error("\tstatusCode = {}", statusCode);
                    log.error("\tresponse = {}", responseString);
                    throw new OposhieldException(ErrorCode.SHAREPOINT_ERROR);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Comprueba si el fichero existe.
     *
     * @param localFilePath Path que se quiere ver.
     */
    private static void checkFileExists(String localFilePath) {
        File file = new File(localFilePath);
        if (file.exists()) {
            throw new OposhieldException(ErrorCode.DUPLICATED_FILE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Convierte una URL de Sharepoint en una URL de graph
     *
     * @param sharePointUrl Sharepoint URL
     * @return Graph URL
     * @throws Exception Si algo ha ido mal.
     */
    private String convertToGraphDownloadUrl(String sharePointUrl) throws Exception {
        final String siteId = getSiteId("Materialesoposiciones");
        String itemId = getItemId(siteId, sharePointUrl);
        return this.sharePointProperties.getGraphApiUrl().replace("{site-id}", siteId).replace("{item-id}", itemId);
    }

    private String getItemId(String siteId, String sharePointUrl) throws Exception {
        IAuthenticationResult result = authenticate();
        String accessToken = result.accessToken();

        String fileName = sharePointUrl.substring(sharePointUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        String itemUrl =
            this.sharePointProperties.getGraphSitesUrl() + siteId + DRIVE_ROOT_SEARCH_TOKEN + fileName + DRIVE_ROOT_SEARCH_TOKEN_CLOSE;

        return getIdFromURL(accessToken, itemUrl);
    }

    /**
     * Obtiene el siteId de graph sobre el nombre de sharepoint
     *
     * @param siteName Nombre del sitio en sharepoint
     * @return SiteId
     * @throws Exception

     */
    @Cacheable("SHAREPOINT_SITE_ID_CACHE")
    public String getSiteId(String siteName) throws Exception {
        IAuthenticationResult result = authenticate();
        String accessToken = result.accessToken();

        final String siteUrl = this.sharePointProperties.getGraphSitesUrl() + "?search=" + siteName;

        return getIdFromURL(accessToken, siteUrl);
    }

    /**
     * Realiza la peticion y procesa el JSON, obteniendo el ID
     * @param accessToken Token
     * @param siteUrl Site URL
     * @return ID String
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws JSONException
     */
    private static String getIdFromURL(String accessToken, String siteUrl) throws IOException, JSONException {
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(siteUrl);
            httpGet.addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, BEARER + accessToken);

            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet)) {
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), CHARSET_JSON_SHAREPOINT_RESPONSE);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                    JSONArray sites = jsonObject.getJSONArray(SITES_TOKEN_VALUE);
                    if (sites.length() > 0) {
                        JSONObject site = sites.getJSONObject(0);
                        return site.getString(EXPECTED_TOKEN_ID);
                    } else {
                        throw new OposhieldException(ErrorCode.SHAREPOINT_ERROR);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new OposhieldException(ErrorCode.SHAREPOINT_ERROR);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've conducted several tests, such as waiting for some time after uploading the file before attempting to download it, or trying to download it immediately, but I haven't been able to achieve anything.

```
2023-05-19 07:29:52.927 ERROR 33372 --- [oposhield-task-2] x.d.p.sharepoint.SharePointClient        : Exception in downloadFile() with cause = NULL 
2023-05-19 07:29:52.928 ERROR 33372 --- [oposhield-task-2] .a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler : Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public java.util.Optional xyz.derivadas.provider.sharepoint.SharePointClient.downloadFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception 

xyz.derivadas.domain.error.OposhieldException: Se ha producido un error relacionado con sharepoint
    at xyz.derivadas.provider.sharepoint.SharePointClient.getIdFromURL(SharePointClient.java:187)
    at xyz.derivadas.provider.sharepoint.SharePointClient.getItemId(SharePointClient.java:143)
    at xyz.derivadas.provider.sharepoint.SharePointClient.convertToGraphDownloadUrl(SharePointClient.java:131)
    at xyz.derivadas.provider.sharepoint.SharePointClient.downloadFile(SharePointClient.java:81)
    at xyz.derivadas.provider.sharepoint.SharePointClient$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$677ff96c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
    at xyz.derivadas.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:109)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor108.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at tech.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Your code throws that exception for several different conditions, so you can't really tell what's happening.  You need to differentiate the exception causes and log all available data, especially including the HTTP status code, so you can troubleshoot.  Without that as a minimum nobody can help.